# For loop in python printing twice

Tags: python

The result from this function is printing out twice for some reason. Is there any reason why? I cant solve this I have been looking at it for an hour now trying to figure why its doing this.

```
import math


def pop1(t):
    r1 = 1 / (1 + (math.e ** -(t)))
    print(r1)

def pop2(t):
    r1 = 1 / (1 + (math.e ** -(t)))
    return r1




def main():
    for t in range(-6, 7):
        print(t, end=" ")
        pop1(t)

    total = 0
    for t in range(-6, 7):
        result = pop2(t)
        total = total + result
        print(t, result)

    print('Total is', total)



main()
```

Comment: Please fix indentation. It seems to only be that. Because after running your code it only printed once.

Comment: mark `print(r1)` and  `print(t, end=" ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not printing twice, it's doing what you make it to do:

Your twice printing is causes of :

```
print(r1)
```

and

```
print(t, end=" ")
```

Second, your indentation of code is not right, your total is not adding result if you are doing `total=total+result` outside of loop , Here are all fix of your code:

```
import math

def pop1(t):
    r1 = 1 / (1 + (math.e ** -(t)))


def pop2(t):
    r1 = 1 / (1 + (math.e ** -(t)))
    return r1

def main():
    for t in range(-6, 7):

        pop1(t)

    total = 0
    for t in range(-6, 7):
        result = pop2(t)
        total+=result
        print(t, result)


    print('Total is', total)

main()
```

Output:

```
-6 0.002472623156634775
-5 0.006692850924284857
-4 0.017986209962091562
-3 0.04742587317756679
-2 0.11920292202211757
-1 0.2689414213699951
0 0.5
1 0.7310585786300049
2 0.8807970779778823
3 0.9525741268224331
4 0.9820137900379085
5 0.9933071490757153
6 0.9975273768433653
Total is 6.5
```

Answer (score 0):

After fixing your indentation, here is a working version:

```
import math

def pop1(t):
    r1 = 1 / (1 + (math.e ** -(t)))
    print(r1)

def pop2(t):
    r1 = 1 / (1 + (math.e ** -(t)))
    return r1

def main():
    for t in range(-6, 7):
        print(t, end=" ")
        pop1(t)

    total = 0    
    for t in range(-6, 7):
        result = pop2(t)
    total = total + result
    print(t, result)

    print('Total is', total)

main()
```

**Output**

```
-6 0.002472623156634775
-5 0.006692850924284857
-4 0.017986209962091562
-3 0.04742587317756679
-2 0.11920292202211757
-1 0.2689414213699951
0 0.5
1 0.7310585786300049
2 0.8807970779778823
3 0.9525741268224331
4 0.9820137900379085
5 0.9933071490757153
6 0.9975273768433653
6 0.9975273768433653
Total is 0.9975273768433653
```